# File lines sorting according to index

Tags: bash

I have a file with the structure below. I want to order its lines by the second column defined by double points on bash, but I do not even know how to start. Would you be nice to help me order it?

`input.txt`

```
a:3:foo
b:1:bar
c:2:goo
```

`output.txt`

```
b:1:bar
c:2:goo
a:3:foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sort`

```
sort -nk2 -t: input.txt
```

Redirect the output to the new file.

```
sort -nk2 -t: input.txt > output.txt
```

---

See `man sort`

Comment: In case the input.txt content comes originally from a pipe, for example, "cat input.txt", does it change substantially the command?

Comment: It should not since sort will process streams as well. like `command_with_output | sort ...`